# How to minimize the execution time of sql select query

Tags: mysql

I have two tables tbl_order and tbl_order user . i need to select all columns from two tables and match it with order id and status of that corresponding tables

i have use below query

```
select o.*
     , u.*
     , o.id as ord_id 
  from tbl_order o
     , tbl_order_user u 
 where (o.online='0' or o.online='2') 
   and o.status='0' 
   and o.id = u.oid
```

My doubt is this query takes max execution time .

How to reduce this max execution time  , is there any alternate query for reducing max execution time .

Can anyone help me . 
Thanks in advance

Comment: use indexes ans primary keys in your tables. Can you share your table structur?

Comment: And select only the columns you actually want ... and given that comma-style joins went out of fashion circa 1992, maybe stop using that

Comment: I would give you some hints because your question has not enough information to determine what is the problem: 1. Use explain method to check why your query is slow 2. Use index for column you query (some columns is indexed by default: primary, unique, foreign)  3. Query exactly what you need (same as @Strawberry suggested)

Answer (score 1):

Use join statements and make sure that you have index on any column you use in WHERE statements and JOIN conditions, with the little info you provided for your schema here is an SQL statement with JOIN:

```
SELECT o.*, 
       u.*, 
       o.id AS ord_id 
FROM   tbl_order o 
       JOIN tbl_order_user u 
    ON o.id = u.oid 
         AND o.online  IN ('0' ,'2' ) AND o.status = '0'
```

RDBMS nowadays optimize your SQL query to be as fast as possible, but if you didn't help it it will not be fast, and as mentioned in the comment retrieve only the fields you need in your app for this query,

**Note**: that you are using string comparison  for `status` and `online` fields.

Comment: Note that this solution evaluates integers as strings

Comment: yes, I was just checking that, I will leave since this is what he posted in the question, will update the post to point that out.

Comment: it seems like the original query in the question is a cross join, right?

Comment: Ok let me try the join query . Ya i have used  cross join for getting all records form two tables